# Figures are not being saved

Tags: matplotlib, eps, savefig

hey so i am trying to use this code

```
plt.savefig("img1.eps", format = "eps",dpi =1000)
```

and i get the following error

```
No suitable pdf to png renderer found.
```

any comments?

Y

Answer (score -1):

I Figured out the answer. I could simply just save it as pdf and it would work.